# OWIN Cookie Authentication Security

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, session-cookies, owin, owin-security

I'm approaching a new project and I am weighing up using MVC5 and Identity thru OWIN.

I am running the scaffolding project for which provides the entity framework user database, register/ sign in etc.. No third party or two factor.

As I currently understand it, OWIN Security is based on the cookie, now, its been a few years since I have dabbled in the Web, BUT I was under the impression that identity and claims should be stored in the session.

I'm inspecting the cookie that is set when a user logs in and various claims are set. I don't actually know what the underlying framework does, and I am struggling to find out:

- are there any technical links? Not about how to implement the interfaces and setup this up, but on the security and best practices.
- What is actually in this cookie and how can I inspect with EditThisCookie what is set? as its encrypted or obfuscated?
- How is this more secure than session?
- If someone, some how got this cookie, could they basically sign in as the same user?
- Does this scale? as normally multiple front ends would talk to the same session server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a lot of samples for you to get your feet wet.
https://github.com/AzureADSamples

To answer some of your questions:

> > > What is actually in this cookie and how can I inspect with EditThisCookie what is set?
> > >       After authentication succeeds, the users identity is stored in a cookie that contains their identity.
> > >
> > > as its encrypted or obfuscated?
> > >       By default the cookie is encrypted and signed. 
> > >       How is this more secure than session?
> > >
> > > If someone, some how got this cookie, could they basically sign in as the same user?
> > >       Unless Channel binding is in effect, yes.
> > >
> > > Does this scale? as normally multiple front ends would talk to the same session server.
> > >       We have found it does scale. SymmetricKey crypto is used, which is fast.

There is the option of using a cache and not putting the details on the wire. This requires a distributed cache, which most developers do not seem to want to do.